# Paypal dynamic return url not working

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to make a paypal payment and I have a problem when returning to my page after the payment is completed.
I want to do it dynamically (so I do not want to set it in the paypal's account option, as I may use this account for other things). This is the form I send to paypal:

```
<form id="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://zopomobile.es/pruebas/modules/rmaforsat/ipn_paypal.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Pago de su orden a Zopomobile.">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="259.12">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="152">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="admin-facilitator@zopomovil.es">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://zopomobile.es/pruebas">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel" value="http://zopomobile.es/pruebas/NO">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">

</form>
```

I have tried changing the "return" variable to "return_url", still not working.

Comment: Have you read the documentation from paypal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automatically re-direct to "http://www.zopomobile.es/pruebas/"
then you need to turn on "Auto Return" on your PayPal profile.
Right now, Auto Return is "OFF" in your profile.

The return parameter is `return`

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Check above link to turn on the "Auto Return" feature.